# Is it ok to use bounty for promotion?

Tags: support, bounty

I have observed some post where the answerer starts a bounty on post where the answer is already right and accepted and sometimes there is only one answer.

Since from [help docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) and [docs2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), bounties are used to get better answer or to promote question which has no answer, am I right ?

So as per the first statement

Is it right behavior to use the bounty to promote the post , where I already have an accepted answer?

If yes then, I hope that there are no other things that I need to take care of , except

- Question quality
- Answer quality
- Not a dupe

Comment: What would be the actual problem here? Putting bounties is a personal freedom you have, much like voting.

Comment: One of the bounty reasons is to **reward an existing outstanding answer**. So everything is working as planned.

Comment: @Gimby thats what i want  to confirm, though from the docs , it's clearly suggest to use it for get working answer , if it not there or to get answer

Comment: If the answer quality is bad, maybe you don't want promotion...

Comment: @NSNoob yeah but if i am the answerer and i am the one who starts a bounty ,so mean i basically using it to promote my answer , hence the question

Comment: @PavneetSingh You can't award a bounty to your own answer.

Comment: @PavneetSingh You can't give it to yourself but you can use it to promote the post.

Comment: @NSNoob yeah i can't , so as a member ,that's the question i am curious about , since it's not mention anywhere that you can use the bounty , just to shwocase your answer to most of the member and according to you , i can use it without any issue

Comment: @PavneetSingh The help page specifically mentions the "Promotional only" bounties and puts extra restrictions on it to avoid abuse so if you are willing to sacrifice that much rep, you have a right to do so.

Comment: @NSNoob that the confusion that , i don't want to abuse SO features though i been searching the concrete answer in docs and on meta to confirm that by doing this i am not abusing anything in any way

Comment: Even if one uses minimal amount of bounty that is 100 rep there are chances that you get less than 100 rep or none rep at all but I think one reason user can give that they want more answer to the question other than accepted answer mentioned.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar yeah it's a risk but it's the answerer who starts the bounty and i have also observed that 100 mount is covered easily in 80% cases

Comment: @CodyGray seems like that's the confirmation i was looking for , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [list of bounty reasons](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/):

> **Authoritative reference needed**
>
> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.
>
> **Canonical answer required**
>
> The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed
>   canonical answer is required to address all the concerns.
>
> **Current answers are outdated**
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given
>   recent changes.
>
> **Draw attention**
>
> This question has not received enough attention.
>
> **Improve details**
>
> The current answers do not contain enough detail.
>
> **Reward existing answer**
>
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional
>   bounty.

So yes it is acceptable to attach bounties to questions with already existing outstanding/lacking answers.

The page also answers how system works in regards to your scenario:

> To discourage overly promotional bounties, **if you are starting a**
>   **bounty on a question you yourself have answered**, **the minimum rep cost**
>   **is 100, increased from the standard 50.**

Also from [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the
>   minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on
>   the first bounty<sup>1</sup>, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and
>   so on).

So judging by these notes, I'd say that you are permitted to use the bounty feature to promote your own answer as long as you don't abuse it by doing it over and over again (Because then it can become really annoying. In any case, If you did that, you'd be quickly down to no rep so yep it's also auto-covered).

<sub>1. In your case it will go 100, 200, 400 presumably given that minimum threshold on promotional bounties on self answers is 2x.</sub>

Comment: yeah , that why i am asking , none of these reasons are there , basically the bounty is used as a showcase for my answer

Comment: @PavneetSingh And what's wrong with it? You are basically giving up a 100 rep for a slot in featured tab. You pay for it and can't grant it back to yourself so most people would not abuse it. What's the issue here?

Comment: If you are saying that a low quality answer may get additional upvotes it does not deserve by the featured attention, then you are underestimating the judgment of the community

Comment: haha , i don't underestimate the power of community , i know i may or may not get those upvotes to cover-up my bounty but since go around bounty tags and open a question which i can attempt to answer and soon i realize the answer is already there and there is even no need of other answer so it's sometime feels little odd